# concatenate dataframe result to another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

So I want to try to concatenate dataframe result to another. Basically I have for loop going through each element of a list that I want to put into a function and the resulted function I want to concatenate to another dataframe. I tried using the code below but the variable 'final' did not concatenate the dataframe and just have the last result of my loop. Anyone can help me with this? thank you

```
for i in range(len(gene_result)):
    result = pd.DataFrame()
    test = dummy_fitness(gene_result[i])  # function that resulted into dataframe
    coords = 'gen '+ str(i) +' coords'
    fitness_points = 'gen ' + str(i) + ' points'
    result[coords] = test.pudo_coords # getting the particular column i want
    result[fitness_points] = test.fit # getting the particular column i want
    final = pd.concat([result])
```

the 'result' variable is shown below and will be different each loop. I want to concatenate the variable 'result' to variable 'final'

```
              gen 0 coords               gen 0 points
0   -6.18360560071739,106.833802730435  8.128732
1   -6.19583084820588,106.850715008823  6.396317
2   -6.17002786742308,106.840075203846  6.050418
3   -6.1956966496,106.822705886667      5.976020
4   -6.18757562077778,106.845673922222  5.703797
5   -6.18317963676,106.81405708         5.622984
6   -6.18141226474074,106.822889814815  5.564183
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need create list of `DataFrame`s by append and then `concat` outside loop:

```
dfs = []
for i in range(len(gene_result)):
    result = pd.DataFrame()
    test = dummy_fitness(gene_result[i])  # function that resulted into dataframe
    coords = 'gen '+ str(i) +' coords'
    fitness_points = 'gen ' + str(i) + ' points'
    result[coords] = test.pudo_coords # getting the particular column i want
    result[fitness_points] = test.fit # getting the particular column i want
    dfs.append(result)
final = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think as your result variable is already a data frame - you can concatenate just like

```py
final = final.append(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method to amend your code would just be pre-declare final and run this

```
final = pd.concat([final, result], axis=1).
```

Alternatively, instead of pre-declaring `final` you could just set `final = result` when `i` is `0`.